# Photoshop - how do I change thickness at both ends of a line?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have this line and i want to make it thin at the both ends. How can i make that? Is there a version of width tool from illustrator in photoshop?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no width tool in Photoshop, nor anything similar.

You would need to use the Pen tool and *draw* a *shape* as opposed to a single path.

Or, use Illustrator which has the width tool, and create the path there, and copy/paste into Photoshop as a **Smart Object**. It won't be a "path" in Photoshop. However, you could always open the Smart Object in Photoshop to adjust the path again in Illustrator.

Another option would be to *expand* the path in Illustrator, copy, then paste into Photoshop as a **Shape Layer** allowing for some easier changes without the need to edit a Smart Object.

... basically `:)` you have to draw a *shape* in Photoshop... or use Illustrator if you don't want to do that.